# Swift Xcode - FittedSheets build Errors: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just updated Xcode to the newest released version Xcode 15. Noq I'm getting build errors with 'FittedSheets' cocoa pod. I am not sure if they have released a fix or not but wanted to see if anyone has encountered and solved these errors.

[image]

I'm using pod in my project. "Pod install" getting successful in older Xcode but Xcode 15 showing errors.

Comment: See https://github.com/gordontucker/FittedSheets/issues/215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the '**FittedSheets**' pod should resolve the issue. If you want to update only 'FittedSheets' without touching other dependencies in the pod, you can use following command

```
pod update FittedSheets
```

Executing this command will download and install the latest version of 'FittedSheets,' which is currently version 2.6.1. You can also check out my comment in the project from https://github.com/gordontucker/FittedSheets/issues/215#issuecomment-1744305645